# JS - why is this not working - any bug?

Tags: javascript, django

I have this code, which adds `page=value` search parameter to url and loads the page. but this is not working, it is not setting the url, do i have any typo there?

```
$(function(){
     $('.page').on('click',function(){
         var page = $(this).text();
         var url = String(window.location);
         var newurl = "";
         if(url.indexOf("?") !== -1){
              if(url.indexOf('page') !== -1){
                 newurl = url.replace(/([&?]page=)[^&]*/, "$1" + String(page));
                 window.location = newurl;                            
              }else{
                 newurl = url +'&page='+String(page);
                 window.location = newurl;
              }
         }else{
             newurl = url +'?page='+String(page);
             window.location = newurl;

          }
        });
  });
```

html

```
<a href="" class="page">1</a>
<a href="" class="page">2</a>
<a href="" class="page">3</a>
<a href="" class="page">4</a>
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly ?

Comment: @adeneo, as I told, it is  not setting the url

Comment: You should check for typos/errors, using your console, before you post.

Comment: @DSG, i already did. i dont see any error, then i posted here

Comment: You need to prevent the default action from occuring `$('.page').on('click',function(e){ e.preventDefault()`. If not, the default action (page reload in this case) will happen. Hence the issue

Comment: @karthikr, YEAAH!!! Thanks dude, i forgot this, i need this because it is ``a``, you are absolutely right

Comment: doniyor - Go ahead, accept the @user3042320's  answer thats fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the browser is following the href of your links.
Use preventDefault to fix your script.

```
$(function(){
     $('.page').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
         var page = $(this).text();
         var url = String(window.location);
         var newurl = "";
         if(url.indexOf("?") !== -1){
              if(url.indexOf('page') !== -1){
                 newurl = url.replace(/([&?]page=)[^&]*/, "$1" + String(page));
                 window.location = newurl;                            
              }else{
                 newurl = url +'&page='+String(page);
                 window.location = newurl;
              }
         }else{
             newurl = url +'?page='+String(page);
             window.location = newurl;

          }
        });
  });
```